JWT Token io.jsonwebtoken.ExpiredJwtException: JWT expired
I have a Spring Boot (with Angular) application.
My application works fine locally, but when I Dockerize my application an error throws when I have to register new user:token expired.
The question which supposes why when I launch in my IDE it works well and no problem is displayed.
application.yml:
spring:
  datasource:
    url: ${SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL}  
    username: ${SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME}
    password: ${SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD}
    driver-class-name: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update
    show-sql: true
    properties:
      hibernate:
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect

server:
  port: 8083

application:
  security:
    jwt:
      secret-key: ${JWT_SECRET_KEY}
      expiration: 86400000000000000000
      refresh-token:
        expiration: 86400000000000000000

mail:
  host: smtp.gmail.com
  port: 587
  username: ${MAIL_USERNAME}
  password: ${MAIL_PASSWORD}
  properties:
    mail:
      smtp:
        auth: true
        starttls.enable: true


docker-compose.yml:
version: '3.8'
services:
  backend:
    image: communicationbackend
    ports:
      - "8083:8083"
    environment:
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL: ${SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL}
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME: ${DB_USERNAME}  # Correct variable name
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}  # Correct variable name
      JWT_SECRET_KEY: ${JWT_SECRET_KEY}
      MAIL_USERNAME: ${MAIL_USERNAME}
      MAIL_PASSWORD: ${MAIL_PASSWORD}
    depends_on:
      - db
    networks:
      - app-network
    env_file:
      - .env  # Charge les variables d'environnement

  frontend:
    image: ramzi/frontend
    ports:
      - "82:80"
    networks:
      - app-network

  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: db-communication
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_USER: ${DB_USERNAME}
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
    ports:
      - "3307:3306"
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
    networks:
      - app-network
    env_file:
      - .env

volumes:
  db_data:

networks:
  app-network:

application.yml:
spring:
  datasource:
    url: ${SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL}
    username: ${SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME}
    password: ${SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD}
    driver-class-name: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update
    show-sql: true
    properties:
      hibernate:
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect

server:
  port: 8083

application:
  security:
    jwt:
      secret-key: ${JWT_SECRET_KEY}
      expiration: 8640000000
      refresh-token:
        expiration: 864000000

mail:
  host: smtp.gmail.com
  port: 587
  username: ${MAIL_USERNAME}
  password: ${MAIL_PASSWORD}
  properties:
    mail:
      smtp:
        auth: true
        starttls.enable: true

.env:
# Variables de la base de données
DB_USERNAME=communication
DB_PASSWORD=password
SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=jdbc:mysql://db:3306/db-communication

# JWT secret
JWT_SECRET_KEY=IS/A4dZ9K2z5tQSV3eGK2i4RGNdiD7qbGGTNq9xUZqO4pqa8+BIan+scnhFPz15pSFWkTGve4YNxWHXt90U5Tg==

# Configurations de l'email
MAIL_USERNAME=****************
MAIL_PASSWORD=***************

I launch my Docker containers, it works. I access my frontend, it is open when I have to register:
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 ()
:8083/PlatformCommunication/v1/register:1 
       Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 ()

So please, how to fix that?
jwtservice:
@Service
public class JwtService {

    @Value("${application.security.jwt.secret-key}")
    private String secretKey;  // Injecting the secret key from application.yml

    @Value("${application.security.jwt.expiration}")
    private long jwtExpiration;

    @Value("${application.security.jwt.refresh-token.expiration}")
    private long refreshExpiration;

  public String extractUsername(String token) {
    return extractClaim(token, Claims::getSubject);
  }

  public <T> T extractClaim(String token, Function<Claims, T> claimsResolver) {
    final Claims claims = extractAllClaims(token);
    return claimsResolver.apply(claims);
  }

  public String generateToken(UserDetails userDetails) {
    return generateToken(new HashMap<>(), userDetails);
  }

  public String generateToken(
          Map<String, Object> extraClaims,
          UserDetails userDetails
  ) {
    return buildToken(extraClaims, userDetails, jwtExpiration);
  }

  public String generateRefreshToken(
          UserDetails userDetails
  ) {
    return buildToken(new HashMap<>(), userDetails, refreshExpiration);
  }

  private String buildToken(
          Map<String, Object> extraClaims,
          UserDetails userDetails,
          long expiration
  ) {
    return Jwts
            .builder()
            .setClaims(extraClaims)
            .setSubject(userDetails.getUsername())
            .setIssuedAt(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()))
            .setExpiration(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + expiration))
            .signWith(getSignInKey(), SignatureAlgorithm.HS256)
            .compact();
  }

  public boolean isTokenValid(String token, UserDetails userDetails) {
    final String username = extractUsername(token);
    return (username.equals(userDetails.getUsername())) && !isTokenExpired(token);
  }

  public boolean isTokenExpired(String token) {
    return extractExpiration(token).before(new Date());
  }

  public Date extractExpiration(String token) {
    return extractClaim(token, Claims::getExpiration);
  }

  private Claims extractAllClaims(String token) {
    return Jwts
            .parserBuilder()
            .setSigningKey(getSignInKey())
            .build()
            .parseClaimsJws(token)
            .getBody();
  }

  private Key getSignInKey() {
    byte[] keyBytes = Decoders.BASE64.decode(secretKey);
    return Keys.hmacShaKeyFor(keyBytes);
  }
}

